# Time complexity (Big-O) of merging two PriorityQueues

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, heap, priority-queue

From the [PriorityQueue Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> Implementation note: this implementation provides
> **O(log(n))** time for enqueuing and dequeuing methods
> `offer`, `poll`, `remove()` and `add`;
> linear time for the `remove(Object)` and `contains(Object)`
> methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods
> `peek`, `element`, and `size`.

So, my question is, would the **O(log(n))** time complexity *hold up* for merging `PriorityQueue`s into one? Or would it be **O(nlog(n))** considering the insertion? And would this change if merging more heaps?

These `PriorityQueue`s are to represent heaps.

Something like this:

```
PriortityQueue<Integer> a = new PriorityQueue<>();
... add elements
PriortityQueue<Integer> b = new PriorityQueue<>();
... add elements
PriorityQueue<Integer> merged = new PriorityQueue<>(a.size() + b.size(), a.comparator()); // Assuming a and b have the same Comparator.
merged.addAll(a);
merged.addAll(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out the method `add` from the class `PriorityQueue` has `O(log(N))` time complexity. If you look at the concrete implementation of the method `addAll` from the class `PriorityQueue`, you see the following:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    if (c == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (c == this)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

So for each element in the collection passed as parameter, the method `add` is called. Therefore, the finally complexity will be `O(Mlog(N))`, where `M` is the number of elements of the collection passed as parameter and `N` is the number of elements of the priority queue.